# WP_Query and NULL meta keys

Tags: plugins, wp-query

I have a bunch of custom posts with two meta keys - `_claimed` and `_average_rating`. The `_average_rating` is only added as a meta key if someone leaves a rating on the post and the `_claimed` meta key is only set to 1 if a user claims the listing - otherwise the listings have no values for `_claimed` or `_average_rating`.

What I would like to do is to arrange the listings as so:

- Show all listings that are claimed first sorted by average review (highest to lowest)
- Show all listings that are unclaimed after this, sorted by average review (highest to lowest)

The following MySQL code was provided to me and this seems to work when I test in phpMyAdmin:

```sql
SELECT p.`ID` , IFNULL( pm.`meta_value` , 0 ) AS claimed, IFNULL( pm2.`meta_value` , 0 ) AS averageRating
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.`post_id` 
AND pm.`meta_key` =  '_claimed'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.`post_id` 
AND pm2.`meta_key` =  '_average_rating'
ORDER BY claimed DESC , averageRating DESC
```

The plugin I use requires the filter to be created in a `WP_Query` - the plugin if you are interested is called FacetWP and below is a sample code of the filters I have at the moment to give you an idea of what is required:

--

```
function my_facetwp_sort_options( $options, $params ) {
    $options['rating'] = array(
        'label' => 'Ripoff',
        'query_args' => array(
         'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_average_rating',
                    'value' => 2,
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                )
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // sort by numerical custom field
            'meta_key' => '_average_rating', // required when sorting by custom fields
            'order' => 'DESC' // descending order
        )
    );
    
    $options['review_desc'] = array(
        'label' => 'Average Review (highest)',
        'sort_custom' => true,
        'query_args' => 
        array(
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'key' => '_claimed',
      'value' => 1,
    'compare' => '=',
     'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
      'key' => '_average_rating'
    )
  )
)
    );
    
    $options['recent_review'] = array(
        'label' => 'Most Recent Reviews',
        'query_args' => array(
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key' => 'date_reviewed',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        )
    );
    
    return $options;
    
}
add_filter( 'facetwp_sort_options', 'my_facetwp_sort_options', 10, 2 );
```

--

Plugin doc here if interested: https://facetwp.com/documentation/facetwp_sort_options/

In order to generate the MySQL query that I require - which I know works I've added the following code:

---

```
function mysite_custom_sort( $orderby, $wp_query ) {
  if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['sort_custom'] ) ) {
    $orderby = 'mt1.meta_value ASC, mt2.meta_value DESC';
  }
  return $orderby;
}
function edit_posts_join_paged($join_paged_statement) {
    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['sort_custom'] ) ) {
    $join_paged_statement = "LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.`post_id` 
AND pm.`meta_key` =  '_claimed'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.`post_id` 
AND pm2.`meta_key` =  '_average_rating'";
    }
    return $join_paged_statement;   
}

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'mysite_custom_sort', 10, 2 );
add_filter('posts_join_paged','edit_posts_join_paged');
```

---

My understanding is that this adds the custom `orderby` and also `JOIN` statements into the WP_Query. However I don't know how to recreate the following code in WP_Query:

```sql
SELECT p.`ID` , IFNULL( pm.`meta_value` , 0 ) AS claimed, IFNULL( pm2.`meta_value` , 0 ) AS averageRating
```

Note that in the above example it sets all values for _claimed and _average_rating as 0 - so that everything is displayed. How can I do this with `WP_Query` though in the confines of how the plugin works as per the requirements I've listed above which are:

- Show all listings that are claimed first sorted by average review (highest to lowest)
- Show all listings that are unclaimed after this, sorted by average review (highest to lowest)

Any input on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Noting that the Facet WP part of this question is off-topic, but you could ask how to do this and then apply the `WP_Query` solution to Facet WP. It's also very uncommon for meta values to be `NULL`, and I'm not sure how you managed to insert `NULL` without resorting to raw SQL. Normally if `_claimed` did not have a value, you would either store `false`, an empty string, or not have a `_claimed` post meta at all.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a way to do both queries in one within WordPress.

If the filters you have in place are working and aren't injecting raw user input into the database query then what is the issue? that is exactly what the filters are there for.

If you are uncomfortable using the filters, then you could do two seperate queries to the database to achieve the same result. It would mean a small performance hit (depending on the size of the database) but this could be mitigated by using the transients API to cache the results.

**EDIT**

If you need to add a key to all your posts already published, something like the below should do the trick it will loop through all products that have no meta key `_average_rating` and add one of 0. *UNTESTED*

I normally do this based on a secret $_GET parameter in admin the delete it after it has run.

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'     => '_average_rating',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ]
    ]
] );

foreach( $query->posts as $post ){
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_average_rating', 0 );
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the response. Not sure if you're understanding my issue. The posts that are 'NULL' are not showing up with WP_Query - I want a way to display the NULL values too. That's all.

Comment: @KostaKondratenko Perhaps a hook on `save_post` to add the meta value of 0 when creating a new post. that way the key would always exist, and you wouldn't have to worry about meta keys the don't exist.?

Comment: Hi Ben, that's a great idea. However that still leaves the problem of the current 1,000+ posts that don't have the meta key values. I can't just delete them. Any input you have on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KostaKondratenko Example added, you can query for keys that don't exist in WP_Query. Have a look through the [documentation on WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), especially the part about `meta_query`

Comment: Thank you Ben - it is much appreciated. I look forward to trying this out later in the day.

Comment: Hi Ben,

I used the following code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c67a990a1902672d8932c954c634f70

However it seems to fetch all listings regardless of if they have a '_claimed' meta field - you can see the output below:

http://wetcheck.com.au/add_claimed.php

Any input you have would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT_EXISTS`